# In Data table first column displaying with tablename.columnname in c#

Tags: c#

When i am running query in data base and fill data table with load method first column name coming with table name.column name(Employee.Name,sal,location) rest of the column name coming only column names present in the database.Why table name appending first column name  while displaying in data table structure please help me in this regards.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

try
{
    using (IDbCommand DbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        DbCommand.CommandText = query;
        IDataReader reader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();
        table.Load(reader);
     }
 }
```

Sample query `Select Employee.Numnber, Employee.salary, Employee.city,dept.deptId from Employee inner join dept where deptiId=EmployeeDeptId`

The actual query is :

```
Select 
    AP_LINE.LINE_NO, AP_LINE.PRODUCT, AP_LINE.QTY, AP_LINE.REQUESTED_DATE, 
    AP_LINE.LIST_PRICE, AP_LINE.CONS_NET_MULT,AP_LINE.NETADDERS, 
    AP_LINE.CONS_NET_PRICE, AP_LINE.Details,TDP_JSP.ID, TDP_JSP.LINE_NO, 
    TDP_JSP_AppInfo.Id
From AP_LINE, CONFIG, TDP_JSP 
    inner join TDP_JSP_AppInfo on TDP_JSP.ID= TDP_JSP_AppInfo.ID 
where AP_LINE.LINE_NO = TDP_JSP.LINE_NO ;
```

Out put in data table as coming below

```
Ap_Line.Line_No,Product,QTY,Requested Date...
```

Comment: The query you posted *doesn't* matche the names. Post the *actual* query, actual names. Are there multiple `Name` columns in the results perhaps? Or some maybe some columns in the `SELECT` clause have aliases, some two-part names?

Comment: Out put in data table as coming below

Comment: Ap_Line.Line_No,Product,QTY,Requested Date...

Answer (score 0):

There are two `LINE_NO` columns in the query, `AP_LINE.LINE_NO` and `TDP_JSP.LINE_NO`. Columns must have unique names, so `DataTable.Load` used the two-part name wherever needed. It that wasn't possible it would start appending indexes or even generate names like `Column0`, `Column1` etc.

In this case though, one of those columns isn't needed. The two tables are join those columns. `WHERE AP_LINE.LINE_NO = TDP_JSP.LINE_NO` is the old-style, frowned-upon join syntax. Those two columns will always have the same data so one of them can be removed.